# Remove id from array of objects in mongodb

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, objectid

I try to delete ObjectID in array of ObjectId.

My model:

```
let directoryCollection = new Schema(
  {
    email: { type: String },
    directory: [{
        name: { type: String },
        list: [ {type: Schema.ObjectId} ]
    }]
  },
  {collection: 'directory'}
);
```

I have a array of ObjectID in *list*.

My code for delete index in my array:

```
let id = mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.body.id);

directoryModel.update({'email': email, 'directory.name': oldDirectory}, {$pull: {'directory.list': id} }, function (req, result) {
    console.log(result);
    res.json('ok');
 });
```

But the result is:

{ ok: 0, n: 0, nModified: 0 }

Email variable and oldDirectory variable ara correct.
My ID is: `5b5e5f34cfcd3906c8e6aa20`

Same in my database:

[image]

What is the problem ?
Thanks you !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, Correct syntax to [`$pull`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/pull/) from array of objects

```
directoryModel.update(
  { "email": email, "directory": { "$elemMatch": { "name": oldDirectory } } },
  { "$pull": { "directory.$.list": id } }
})
```

Comment: This would not work. It would pull the entire `directory` instead of the element in the array. He already tried this.